# Print binary value instead of hexadecimal

Tags: types, lua

I'm reading a 32 bit binary value from an FPGA. This is not a number, each bit represents an error flag for a part of the system. This means that it's important that it is displayed in binary format not hex or decimal.

I simply wish to print the value and treat it as binary.

For example:

```
printf("Error table: /n %x /n", error_table);
```

will print the value in hex format. What do I need to do to print this in binary format?

I'd like the result displayed onscreen to be more like:

```
Error table:
00101101001010000010010010110101
```

Do I need to convert it to a string?

Comment: looks like an answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079853/lua-print-integer-as-a-binary

Comment: Looks like I'll be able to use that, thanks.